# AWS sync folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is a workflow I have to follow -

- Take data from one endpoint,

  Sync to my bucket

  Process the data

  Delete data

  Repeat process next day

So,I have to sync a folder in AWS bucket from another AWS bucket. I have to get only files of a day into my bucket on daily basis. But when I run this command -

```
aws s3 --region=us-east-1 sync  s3://X.Y.c-h/abc/2015/09/07 to s3://XX/YY/2015/09/07
```

I get the following error

```
Unknown options: s3://XX/YY/2015/09/07
```

Also, if I do

```
aws s3 --region=us-east-1 sync  s3://X.Y.c-h/abc to s3://XX/YY
```

Then I get all data that was in other bucket. I just need that particular day data not all. 
Any help? I am learning cloud system.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `to`, eg:

```
aws s3 --region=us-east-1 sync  s3://X.Y.c-h/abc s3://XX/YY
```